# Batch file grabbing multiple variables from text document

Tags: batch-file, variables, text

I am trying to make a batch file 'account' system, but I don't want to put the usernames and passwords in plain sight. I want them to be hidden in text files. I know its possible to pull a variable from a text file, but I only know how to pull one from the top of the document. I want to have multiple variables per document so that way there can be more than one 'account' login per document.

My code:

```
 @echo off
title Secure Account System (SAS) V 0.1



:ssoa
cls
color 04
echo =--------------=
echo  Hello. Welcome
echo  to the SAS 0.1
echo =--------------=
echo Sign in here.
set /p ssos=Username:
set /p ssod=Password:

if %ssos% == default if %ssod% == user goto baselog

:plzno
echo Don't press enter without correct information.
timeout 2 >nul
goto ssoa

:baselog
cls
color 02
echo =--------------=
echo Default Terminal
echo =--------------=
echo type help for help
set /p termbase=SAS:\default\:

if %termbase% == help goto helpba
if %termbase% == logoff goto ssoa
if %termbase% == end exit

:whydoudo
echo Enter a correct command.
timeout 2 >nul
goto baselog

:helpba
echo help   - Puts you here.
echo logoff - Logs you off.
echo end    - Shuts down the SAS.
pause
goto baselog
```

That's all I have. I need it to pull variables so that way the `'if %ssos% == 1 if %ssod% == 2 goto something'`
 works like

```
'if %ssos% == %pulled_Variable% if %ssod% == %pulledVariable% goto something'
```

Comment: How do you plan on hiding the text file with the account credentials?

Comment: @Squashman With a HIDDEN text file.

Comment: If you say so. If you think you can hide it good luck.

Comment: @Squashman I did it with one variable.

Comment: [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)

Comment: For /f is the entire command?

Comment: show a text file with usernames\password that you want to use for it / p.s. always use construction like if "%ssos%"=="%pulled_Variable%" with quotas.